# What does 'the subspace W = ( < \{> v_1 \})^o' mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Can anyone help me understand the notation used at the end of this sentence?

'Now we proceed to the dual space $V'$, and the subspace W = ( < {> v_1 })^o'

Comment: It might be helpful if you provided some more context or maybe a screenshot of what you're reading.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the formula in question is $W = ( \langle \{ v_1 \} \rangle )^\circ$, and is supposed to be interpreted as the annihilator of the subspace spanned by $v_1$.

Comment: @ZhenLin: That makes a lot of sense, I believe this to be a typo in my notes.